# installing box2d gym ai

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I want to train DQN on CarRacing environmnet but when I want to import it using bellow command there is an error.

```
env = gym.make('CarRacing-v0').unwrapped

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
```

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_4868/4193301300.py in 
16
17
---> 18 env = gym.make('CarRacing-v0').unwrapped
19
20 # set up matplotlib

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py in make(id, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py in make(self, path, **kwargs)
127         if ":" in path:
128             mod_name, _sep, id = path.partition(":")
--> 129             try:
130                 importlib.import_module(mod_name)
131             # catch ImportError for python2.7 compatibility

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py in make(self, **kwargs)
87
88
---> 89 class EnvRegistry(object):
90     """Register an env by ID. IDs remain stable over time and are
91     guaranteed to resolve to the same environment dynamics (or be

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py in load(name)
26
27     Args:
---> 28         id (str): The official environment ID
29         entry_point (Optional[str]): The Python entrypoint of the environment class (e.g. module.name:Class)
30         reward_threshold (Optional[int]): The reward threshold before the task is considered solved

AttributeError: module 'gym.envs.box2d' has no attribute 'CarRacing'

also when I run the code :

```
pip install gym[all]
```

I get the error :

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
```

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_4868/4193301300.py in 
16
17
---> 18 env = gym.make('CarRacing-v0').unwrapped
19
20 # set up matplotlib

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py in make(id, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py in make(self, path, **kwargs)
127         if ":" in path:
128             mod_name, _sep, id = path.partition(":")
--> 129             try:
130                 importlib.import_module(mod_name)
131             # catch ImportError for python2.7 compatibility

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py in make(self, **kwargs)
87
88
---> 89 class EnvRegistry(object):
90     """Register an env by ID. IDs remain stable over time and are
91     guaranteed to resolve to the same environment dynamics (or be

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py in load(name)
26
27     Args:
---> 28         id (str): The official environment ID
29         entry_point (Optional[str]): The Python entrypoint of the environment class (e.g. module.name:Class)
30         reward_threshold (Optional[int]): The reward threshold before the task is considered solved

AttributeError: module 'gym.envs.box2d' has no attribute 'CarRacing'

also when I run the code :

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using windows for using OpenAI gym which is not officially supported.
Gym installation for windows is not stable. Linux and Mac are officially supported. I recommend this video [Installing OpenAI Gym (gym[all]) on Linux, Windows and Mac](https://youtu.be/e3DyCg0fgx0) for installing gym in linux.
You can also use wsl2 in windows which I have tried and it does work.

Also, this doc [gym 0.7.4](https://pypi.org/project/gym/0.7.4/) helped me to set up the display in using wsl2(alias linux server according to the docs).

An individual installation like box2d did not work for me. Try to install all as said in the video(takes a lot of space  but there is no other option)